# Laravel dusk asserting for 404 errors

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-dusk

I'm trying to use laravel dusk to test for 404 not found error. Specifically when loading an image. After reading the laravel dusk documentation I've found no asserts that could help me test if a 404 exception occurs.

Is there a good way of getting a browser test to know whether a resource has failed loading or is it simply not possible?

Comment: have you tried assertNotFound()?

Comment: I don't think assertNotFound is part of laravel dusk

Comment: Just checked now and it says it's an undefined method

Comment: Sorry, I meant you can use it's part of the illuminate Foundation testing package, so you can do something like $this->get("url")->assertNotFound(); in your phpunit tests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is intentionally no way to access HTTP status codes:

https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/422
https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/issues/470

Comment: Read up on the link you sent me and it all makes sense. I'll have to implement tests at another level to try and test for this issue. Thanks for the information :)

Comment: Done, sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0):

You can use `browser -> driver -> manage() -> getLog('browser')` to get the log and see if there is a 404 Error

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had been fighting this for hours. I read @Robert Davids answer but did not know what to do with it. A `dd($browser->driver->manage()->getLog('browser');` let me see what was returned. I had to drill down into it to retrieve just the message string.

```
..array:1 [ // tests/Browser/test_404_is_given.php:56
  0 => array:4 [
    "level" => "SEVERE"
    "message" => "https://example.com/customer/fa866b18-ccd9-11ed-8b33-cdf257dc49d8 - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
    "source" => "network"
    "timestamp" => 1687317936976
  ]
]
```

Here is my working code that combines `assertStringContainsString`, array traversals, and browser logs to successfully test on a 404 page.

```
    public function test_404_is_given(): void
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/url_that_will_generate_404')
            $this->assertStringContainsString("404", $browser->driver->manage()->getLog('browser')[0]["message"]);

            //dd($browser->driver->manage()->getLog('browser')[0]["message"]);
        });
    }
```