# Laravel dusk assert json response

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-dusk

I have a form where the page does not redirects to another page when the submission is successful. The submission is done using an ajax HTTP POST call, server responds with HTTP status code as 200, 422, 500 depending on the conditions.

I want to assert if the response from the ajax call is 200. How do I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711350/laravel-dusk-asserting-for-404-errors

Comment: Does that answer your question?